# Yii2 gridview отдельный фильтр

Tags: php, yii2, gridview, filter

Есть в Yii2 виджет **GridView**, который может выводить данные в виде таблицы, также можно указывать модель фильтра, в таблице появляются инпуты для фильтрации данных. Меня не устраивает стандартное отображение этих фильтров, мне бы хотелось вынести эти самые фильтры вне таблицы, можно это как-то реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Буквально на днях информацию об отдельной форме фильтрации добавили в официальную документацию - [англ.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#separate-filter-form), [рус.](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/output-data-widgets.md#%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Вкратце:

**1)** Создайте частичное представление `_search.php`:

```
<div class="post-search">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => ['index'],
        'method' => 'get',
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'creation_date') ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Искать', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::submitButton('Сбросить', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

**2)** Включите его в нужное место в представление `index.php` (где выводится сам виджет GridView):

```
<?= $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]) ?>
```

**3)** Скорректируйте соответствующим образом поисковую модель (правила валидации, условия фильтрации).

**P.S.** При использовании Gii данная форма уже включена по умолчанию в генерации кода CRUD, вам остается только подкорректировать ее и раскомментировать вывод.

Comment: Спасибо, я сам тоже уже сегодня разобрался частично :)

Comment: есть официальная русская документация? О_о за это тоже спасибо :D

Comment: @arkadij_ok Да, русская есть, но она не всегда актуальная и только в исходниках на Github.